# possible mistake in formulation of zero and alternative hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

from the book, i have following task

[image]

i think there  is error in formulation of alternative hypothesis , because word at least means minimum,there for instead of  $p < 0.77$, it  should be 
$p \ge 0.77$  , so instead of left test,  it is right test and  $\alpha=0.01$ means that for right test we will have $1-0.01=0.99$ and  critical value is

=NORMSINV(0.99)

which is equal to  2.33

am i right?

Comment: Do you have the rest of the problem? The question says "test the claim."

Comment: no no others is clear

Comment: well, what was the test statistic (less than -2.33?) and what did they conclude?

Comment: i still think you are right that "at least X" means $\geq x,$ and that this is an error in the problem.

Comment: any way i will not give this example to my students

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to interpret the intent of the question, I would say that the hypothesis should be $$H_0 : p = 0.77 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_1 : p > 0.77.$$  The reason is that what is claimed is that at least $77\%$ of people oppose replacement, and in order to support this claim, the evidence needs to suggest with a high degree of confidence (in this case, $99\%$) that the true proportion is in fact this high.  If we use the test described in the given answer, this could only lend evidence to the contrary--i.e., that the true proportion is less.  It cannot support a finding that the claim is true.

In general, what is claimed should be the alternative (research) hypothesis.

---

It is worth noting that because the point estimate $\hat p = 55/80 = 0.6875 < 0.77$, the automatic conclusion of the test is to fail to reject $H_0$.  There is not sufficient evidence to suggest the true proportion is so high.

Answer (score 1):

The verbal claim is that "at least 77%" oppose replacing...etc. I would have formulated as follows:

$H_0: p\geq 0.77, H_1: p < 0.77.$

While what is claimed should generally be the alternate hypothesis, the wording of the problem suggests the authors felt that the seriousness of rejecting a true high estimate of public objection was greater than wrongly overestimating public objection.

The test is thus left-tailed as the authors indicate. If the point estimate is low enough (leading to  a value less than -2.33) we would reject $H_0$ as formulated with high confidence.

The text states clearly, "to see if this claim is valid...etc." And associates this with "$H_0: p = 0.77$ (claim)." In context I think they meant to put $H_0: p\geq 0.77$ (claim).

Comment: but why it can't be right tailed test ?

Comment: @datodatuashvili: Because the null hypothesis fails if the test statistic falls too far to the left (i.e., sample p is too low).

Comment: yes but at least means minimum, therefore something is greater or equal  then ,  what i have learned from the book is that when claim is about equal it should be  zero hypothesis, rest  are considered  for alternative(less then or greater then)

Comment: @datodatuashvili: yes, if the hypothese is = then <,> are the alternatives. If >= is the hypothesis, < is the alternative.

Comment: thanks  in advance and congratulate   Easter   festival